# I trained an LSTM classifier (TF) in one script, loaded into another and it gives different predictions on the same data?

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I've trained an LSTM multi-class classifier which is performing well on training/validation and also a test set. I have then saved the model (code below), and loaded this model into another notebook. The issue is that despite the data being exactly the same, the predictions are different in the new script to that which was output in the training script.

Pulling my hair out on this one...

```
# save model
now = str(datetime.now()).split(' ')
lstm.save(f'./model saves/{now[0]}/LSTM_{target_output}_{model_type}_{now[1].split(".")[0]}')
```

```
file = './model saves/2023-03-30/LSTM_multi_multi_00:38:48'
lstm = tf.keras.models.load_model(file, custom_objects = {'c1_recall_metric':c1_recall_metric,
                                                          'c2_recall_metric':c2_recall_metric,
                                                          'c3_recall_metric':c3_recall_metric})
```

I have checked everything triple times in terms of the same StandardScaler (loaded in also), and all the data pre-processing code is exactly the same as the previous script. I've checked the data and it matches the original data exactly. I've inspected the weights and they are all the same. The architecture is exactly the same also.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the randomness is not being preserved while we run the model again.

Refer to this code snippet taken from this [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/) :

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

You will need to add this before your code to see the same randomness the next time you run your code.

You can view the same in more detail on the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed).